# if result.responseText.match not exist

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

i don't know mutch about javascript but i found this greasemonekey script that i'm trying to edit.

```
var rating = document.links;

for (i = 0; i < rating.length; i++) { 
if (rating[i].href.indexOf("/shows/") != -1){

    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: 'get',
        url: rating[i].href,
        onload: function (i) {return function(result) { 

                rate = result.responseText.match(/<span class="rating">(.*)<\/span>/);
                result = rate[1].substring(0,3);

                rat = document.createElement("div");
                rat.className = 'rate';
                rat.innerHTML = result;
                rating[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rat, rating[i].nextSibling);
        }}(i)
    });
}
}
```

So it search all the links on the page and if the link contains /shows/ it search for the value:

```
<span class="rating"><\span>
```

if its found it shows the result in the div i created. so far so good!

But some of those links doenst have `<span class="rating"><\span>`

On those links i like it to say "not found" But i can't figured it out how to :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rate = result.responseText.match(/<span class="rating">(.*)<\/span>/);
if(rate){
  // Existing code.
  result = rate[1].substring(0,3);

  rat = document.createElement("div");
  rat.className = 'rate';
  rat.innerHTML = result;
  rating[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rat, rating[i].nextSibling);
}else{
  // Your new "not found" code.
  // Something like this, depending upon what you want to do:

  rat = document.createElement("div");
  rat.className = 'rate-not-found';
  rat.innerHTML = "Rate not found.";
  rating[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rat, rating[i].nextSibling);
}
```